# Return error value if an error occurs, otherwise, continue with function

Tags: c++, if-statement, return-value

Is there any better (more readable and / or with less duplicated code) way to write this in C++?

```
int func()
{
  int error = foo(); // can return true/false
  if (error != 0) // if an error is returned from foo(), pass it up to the caller of func()
    return error;

  // otherwise, proceed
  error = bar(); // can return true/false
  if (error != 0)
    return error;

  return error; // all calls succeeded, return 0.
}
```

Comment: There are *many* ways to write it, but they are all matter of personal opinion and subjectivity.

Comment: But I can tell you that this is one situation where using labels and `goto` is usually accepted.

Comment: As short as I could: `int func() { int error; return ((error = foo()) != 0) || (error = bar()), error; }` (Readability was not a design goal but I spent some parentheses which were not necessarily needed...)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I was hoping for something that doesn't include a lot of duplicated code. Usually when you see duplicated code, it's time to rethink.

Comment: If it is okay that a `1` will be returned on every error you can do `return foo() || bar();` or `return -(foo() || bar());` if you want to return `-1` on error.

Comment: @mch that could work, however, in the real case this related to, the return value is an `enum`, where `0` is all clear, and `!0` is some descriptive error code.

Comment: Isn't this why exceptions are invented?

Comment: What you want is called a _monad_.

Comment: @Chiel If only I was working with a library that used exceptions... :/

Comment: I just realized that `!= 0` is actually redundant. So I shorten my first approach to: `int func() { int error; return (error = foo()) || (error = bar()), error; }`

Comment: @Chiel It really depends. Remember that exceptions are not cheap if thrown, which is why they should only be used on *exceptional* events. Simple error checking or validation or other cases where errors are as common as successes are really not a good match for exceptions.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit So stack-unwinding is cheap these days?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Yes, very. I might accept `goto` and labels in an exceptionally time-constrained environment. And I mean exceptionally. (Irony)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Okay, good to know. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want an indication of true (non-zero) or false (zero) returned, rather than the actual value returned by your called functions

```
 int func()
 {
      return foo() || bar();
 }
```

This will return `1` if either `foo()` or `bar()` return non-zero, with short circuiting so `bar()` will not be called if `foo()` returns non-zero.   In this case, consider returning `bool` rather than `int`.

If `foo()` or `bar()` can return a range of non-zero values (e.g. indicating different error conditions) and you need to preserve those

```
 int func()
 {
     int error = foo();
     if (!error) error = bar();
     return error;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your version looks nice enough. The only thing I'd avoid is reusing the same variable, but instead use one separate variable per error and scope it tightly:

```
int func()
{
  if (int const error = foo())
    return error;

  if (int const error = bar())
    return error;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
void func()
{
   foo();
   bar();
}
```

where an exception is thrown up to the caller(s) by either function, if something unexpected occurs.

Error codes are a C-ism.

Comment: Now wait for the misguided "errors aren't an exceptional occurrence"/"don't use exceptions for code flow" tantrums to come rolling in ;)

Comment: Error codes are definitely a `C`-ism, especially when you are working with a hardware library dll that's written in... you guessed it: `C`.

Comment: @Drise: Doesn't mean you need to succumb to that technique yourself. Don't let it leak to the rest of your application.

Comment: Yea, that's why I'm hiding as much as I can under a class. At the top level, the class will throw if something catastrophic happens.

Comment: @Drise: There you go then ;)

Comment: @Drise Your class should wrap `foo` and `bar` then, and turn each of their returned error codes into exceptions so that you can compose your wrapped functions into `void func() { this->foo(); this->bar(); }`

Answer (score 0):

If you tend to use this kind of construction often, I'd advise you to define a [monad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29) to hide the repetitive behaviour. A simple implementation would go like this.

#### Implementation

```
template<typename Return, Return True>
class Monad
{
    Return _result;

public:
    Monad() : _result(True) {}

public:
    template<typename Function, typename... Args>
    Monad&
    call(Function f, Args ...args)
    {
        if (_result == True) {
            _result = f(args...);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Return result() { return _result; }
};
```

#### Usage

```
bool f()      { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; return true; }
bool g(int n) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; return n == 42; }
bool h()      { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; return true; }

int main()
{
    Monad<bool, true> m;
    const bool result = m.call(f)
                         .call(g, 56)
                         .call(h)
                         .result();
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << result << "\n";
}
```

In this case, only `f()` and `g(56)` are called (`h()` is not); `result()` returns `false`.

<kbd>[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4dcc9a3e1436440a)</kbd>

Comment: That's really neat, something I wouldn't have thought of.

Answer (score -1):

You want `outcome<T>`.

https://ned14.github.io/outcome/

But you are going to introduce bigger compile times for the sake of saving a few keystrokes though.

Comment: Mind elaborating a bit more on the contents of the link?

Comment: it is basically @YSC's answer implemented as a library proposed for inclusion into Boost (and then maybe standard C++ one day).

Comment: I meant that, as a reviewer, you commonly see this: `While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes`.

It would be best to elaborate more in case the link becomes dead (and the main content of your answer dies with it). See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143663/186397 or https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/186397